# remove just a item by angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I just want to remove an item, but my code removes all the items.
I don't understand and can't find another solution,

please help

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, data) in datas">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.name" ng-change="datas.$save(data)" />  
<input type="text" ng-model="data.age" ng-change="datas.$save(data)" />
<a ng-click="removeItem(id)">delete</a>
</div>


ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
authData = ref.getAuth();
obj = $firebaseObject(ref);    
obj.$remove(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `FIREBASE_URL` points to your list (or even entire database), then indeed your code will delete that list. This is expected behavior. Since you're using `$firebaseObject`, calling `$remove()` on that will remove the object; in this case the entire list of items.

To remove only the item with `id`:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var items = $firebaseArray(ref);    
items.$remove(items.$indexFor(id));
```

This is a bit convoluted btw, you can just as easily do:

```
new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL).child(id).remove();
```

This has been asked before, so please become friendly with search:

- [Angularfire: Delete item(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105390/angularfire-delete-items)
- [AngularFire $remove item from Array using a variable in Firebase reference does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624591/angularfire-remove-item-from-array-using-a-variable-in-firebase-reference-does)
- [AngularFire - Remove Single Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496045/angularfire-remove-single-item)
- [Delete single item in Firebase with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437951/delete-single-item-in-firebase-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

To delete just a single property from a Firebase object use the JavaScript delete operator and then `$save` the object.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, data) in datas">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" ng-change="datas.$save()" />  
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.age" ng-change="datas.$save()" />
    <button ng-click="removeItem(key)">delete</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var authData = ref.getAuth();

$scope.datas = $firebaseObject(ref);

$scope.removeItem = function(key) {
    delete $scope.datas[key];   
    $scope.datas.$save();
};
```

For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference -- delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).